# .htaccess mapping www & non-www to folder and maintain www

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am no `.htaccess` expert and extremely rarely use it. I went through several solutions on Net and SO but no luck still. So I have one IP says `1.2.3.4` that has sub folder of my wordpress application says ABC in the `/var/www/html/`. DNS has been setup so that `www.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` point to IP `1.2.3.4`.

I have my content in `.htaccess` file as below and it only supports `mydomain.com`. The content is displayed as expected except when I put `www.mydomain.com` it displays Linux home page.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ABC/
RewriteRule (.*) /ABC/$1
```

When I put `www.mydomain.com` the browser automatically change the URL to `mydomain.com`.

Apart from that, I would also like to have all domain with `www`. Means request from `mydomain.com` will be displayed as `www.mydomain.com`. Later I will just put `www.mydomain.com` in the URL config of my wordpress. Some helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Switch back to your old .htaccess code. I got it more clear after your last update. You have wordpress files in "public_html/ABC" but need your website url as www.example.com. Let me explain step by step.

1. Paste your old code in .htaccess.
2. copy (do not move) the index.php and .htaccess file from the /ABC folder to the "public_html" of your site.
3. Find one rule in "public_html/index.php" as "require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );" and replace it with "require( dirname( **FILE** ) . '/ABC/wp-blog-header.php' );" (do not edit the index.php file in the folder /ABC!!)
4. change ONLY the "Site Address (URL)" in the general settings (Settings -> General) to "http://www.example.com".

Comment: Thanks for the response. Here is the observation:
`www.mydomain.com` displays Linux test page. Seems not working on mapping the folder.`mydomain.com` displays mydomain.com/ABC in the browser but the content of application is there. How to hide the folder?

Comment: UPDATE: I changed to `SITEURL` of Wordpress to `www.mydomain.com`. So when I go to `mydomain.com` it displays `www.mydomain.com/ABC` plus seems like it is missing JS and CSS files.

Comment: Thanks to your answer. I managed to get what I want with my own solution as posted below. I haven't tried your approach in your answer. But it is good to have alternative. Do you think my solution below good? Any consequences?

Answer (score 0):

So finally I managed to get what I want to be working with below solution. Hopefully this will help somebody out there:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Whatever request coming to the server, add www to it
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Map the www URL to the subfolder in root directory    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.myurl\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/thefolder/
RewriteRule (.*) /thefolder/$1
```

For Wordpress part, I have put codes in `wp-config.php` as below:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://www.myurl.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.myurl.com');
```

Thank you. Cheers.

**UPDATE**
I have just realized that after the changes above, I could not able to login to my WP admin page. This is due to wrong redirect. It looks something like `http://www.myurl.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fthefolder%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

When I remove the `thefolder` from URL it redirects to expected page. Can somebody advice on this?